# How can i get list of items by their groupName with action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the Layout that shows menu from ThemeGroups list, when I click on one of menu items, it should go to page that shows all of theme in this ThemeGroup, but when i do that, get this error:

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
    The resource cannot be found.
    Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
    dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is 
    temporarilyunavailable.  
    Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

    Requested URL: /Home/Browse/1

    Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
    ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225
```

I have the "ThemeModel.cs" that gives me properties of themes, the "ThemeGroupsModel.cs" that gives me "id" and "ThemeGroupName" and have the folder whith name "Services" in my project that has the class "ThemeSrv.cs".
this class has one method with this codes:

```
   public List<ThemesModel> getAllTheme(short ThemeGrId)
    {
   List<ThemesModel> ThemeList = new List<ThemesModel>();
        ThemesModel themeTemp;
        using (var context = new EShopThemeDBEntities(idbconnection.ConnStr))
        {
            var ThemesDb = (from o in context.Themes
                            where o.ThemeGroupId == ThemeGrId
                            select o).ToList();
            if (ThemesDb != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in ThemesDb)
                {
                    themeTemp = new ThemesModel();

                    themeTemp.ThemeID = item.ThemeID;
                    themeTemp.ThemeName = item.CodeName;
                    themeTemp.HtmlF = item.Html;
                    themeTemp.JoomlaF = item.Joomla;
                    themeTemp.Image = item.Image;
                    themeTemp.PsdF = item.PSD;
                    themeTemp.UploadDate = item.UploadDate;
                    themeTemp.UnitPrice = (float)item.UnitPrice;
                    ThemeList.Add(themeTemp);
                }
            }
        }
        return ThemeList;
    }
```

I have the HomeModel that has these properties:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using EshopTheme.Services;

   namespace EshopTheme.Models
   {
public class HomeModel
{
    public MenuSrv MenuList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ThemeGroupsModel> ThemeGr { get; private set; }

    public ThemeSrv ThemesByGrId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ThemesModel> AllThemes { get; private set; }

   public HomeModel()
    {
        this.MenuList = new MenuSrv();
        this.ThemeGr = this.MenuList.getAllThemeGroup();

        this.ThemesByGrId = new ThemeSrv();
        this.AllThemes = ThemesByGrId.getAllTheme(2);
    }
```

this is my action in HomeController:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Browse(short ThemeGroupId)
    {
        var themes = new ThemeSrv();

        return View(themes.getAllTheme(ThemeGroupId));
    }
```

and these codes are in my "_LayoutMain.cshtml" to show menu in all of my pages:

```
   @{EshopTheme.Models.HomeModel hm = new EshopTheme.Models.HomeModel();     
   }
     <ul id="menu">
                @foreach (var item in hm.ThemeGr)
                {

                    <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.ThemeGroupName, "Browse", "Home", 
                    new { id = item.ThemeGroupId }, new { @class = "linkMenu" })

                    </li>
                } </ul>
```

i create the view for "Browse" action with name "Brows.cshtml" to show the results when i click on one item (one of theme groups like "sport") in menu , it shows the list of all themes with the name group "sport".

```
   @{ EshopTheme.Models.HomeModel hm = new EshopTheme.Models.HomeModel();

ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMain.cshtml";
   }


   <ul id="themeList">

@foreach (var item in hm.ThemesByGrIds )
{
    <li><a href="@Html.ActionLink(item.ThemeName, "Browse", "home",
 new { id=item.ThemeID })">
        <img src="@item.Image" alt="@item.ThemeName" /><br />
        <span>Theme Name: @item.ThemeName </span>
        <br /><span>Upload date: @item.UploadDate
        </span>
    @*  <span>price: @item.UnitPrice</span>*@
         </a></li>

}
```

what is my problem??
Thanks for helping...

Comment: Browse(short ThemeGroupId)-
change it to -> Browse(int ThemeGroupId) maybe it works

Comment: Browse(short ThemeGroupId)- change it to -> Browse(int id) it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely getting a 404 because your routing is misconfigured and/or you are trying to `GET` a `POST` action result. Try this

**Route**

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Browse",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{themeGroupId}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", themeGroupId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**ActionResult**

```
public ActionResult Browse(short themeGroupId)
{
    var themes = new ThemeSrv();
    return View(themes.getAllTheme(themeGroupId));
}
```

You need to tell the routing engine about the parameter you want to pass to the `ActionResult`

Comment: Thanks all...

my problem has solved by your helping.

I delete [httpPost] that is before my "Brows" action, and change "Browse(short ThemeGroupId)" to "Browse(int id)" ...